# Reference iterator in parallel loop

Tags: python, parallel-processing, joblib

I'm trying to reference the iteration value `i` in a parallel loop using Joblib. I'm getting the error `NameError: name 'i' is not defined`. Below is my code:

```
def sub5():
    curveplots = []
    nodes = node_matrix[:,i,:].T
    curveplots = bezier.Curve(nodes, degree=2).evaluate_multi(np.linspace(0,1,bezier_precision)).T
    return curveplots
curveplots = Parallel(n_jobs=-1,)(delayed(sub5)()for i in range(l))
```

I'm assuming this is because `i` is defined when I call `Parallel`, after the function `sub5`. But I'm not sure how to get around this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Pass `i` as an actual argument?

Comment: Put `i` here `def sub5(i):` and here `delayed(sub5)(i)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski that was it! Thank you!